# Routing Error No route matches [DELETE] "/topics"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

Trying to get delete action for topics controller to work properly. 
 Here is my topics controller

```
def destroy
@topic = Topic.find(params[:id])

if @topic.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "\"#{@topic.title}\" Topic was deleted!"
  redirect_to topics_path(@topic)
else
  flash.now[:alert] = "An error occurred. Please try again."
  render :show
end
```

end

My routes:

```
 resources :topics do
    resources :bookmarks, except: [:index]
  end
```

My delete link on my index view:

```
<%= link_to "Delete Topic", @topic, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this topic?' } %>
```

Really don't understand what I am missing.

Comment: What does `polymorphic_url(@topic)` give you? My guess is that you have either reassigned `@topic` to something inadvertent or bungled `ActionDispatch::Routing::PolymorphicRoutes` somehow so that its giving the collection route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with these changes:

```
def destroy
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])

  if @topic.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "\"#{@topic.title}\" Topic was deleted!"
    redirect_to topics_path
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = "An error occurred. Please try again."
    render :show
  end
end
```

Delete Link:

```
<%= link_to "Delete Topic", topic_path(@topic), method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this topic?' } %>
```